# Inequality in recurrence relation

Tags: inequality, recurrence-relations

I'm having a mental block understanding what is probably a simple inequality in a guess and check example for a recurrence relation. Would someone please explain to me how they obtain the inequalities at the very bottom here? [image]

Answer (score 1):

If $n\ge 2^{2/a}$, then

$$\lg n\ge\lg\left(2^{2/a}\right)=\frac2a$$

by definition, so $\lg n\ge\frac2a$. Multiplying both sides by $\frac{a}2n$, we see that $\frac{a}2n\lg n\ge n$. But then

$$\frac{a}2n\lg n+n\le\frac{a}2n\lg n+\frac{a}2n\lg n=an\lg n\;.$$

Comment: Uhh still confused. The part I don't get is the very first part where you said if n >= 2^2/a and also the 1 <= (a/2)logn part.

Comment: @Jake: First I took logs base $2$ of both sides: $n\ge 2^{2/a}$, so $\lg n\ge\lg\left(2^{2/a}\right)$. But $\lg 2^x=x$ by definition, so $\lg n\ge\frac2a$. Now multiply both sides by $a$ and divide both sides by $2$. I’ve incorporated this into my answer.

Comment: No i mean i dont understand your starting point. How do you get n >= 2^(2/a) in the first place?

Comment: @Jake: You just need an upper bound that’s valid for all sufficiently large $n$. The calculation shows that the induction step can be carried out if $n\ge 2^{2/a}$, and all that remains is to choose a suitable $a$.